# Google Sheets API v4 Delete not Clear Row

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to delete a row in google sheets with the code below. However, when I execute the code it only clears the data in that row but doesn't delete the entire row. I'm not sure if my question makes sense, so I attached some images to make it clear! Any help is appreciated, I tried a bunch of different ways but none of them seem to work the way I need it and I'm not even sure if it is possible to delete a row instead of clearing.

```py
    spreadsheet_data = [{"deleteDimension": {"range": {"sheetId": 0,"dimension": "ROWS","startIndex": dataidx,"endIndex": dataidx}}}]
    update_data= {"requests": spreadsheet_data}
    request = SERVICESHEET.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SHEETID, body=update_data)
    response = request.execute()
```

Original:

[image: 1]

What my code does:

[image: 2]

What I want my code to do:

[image: 3]

Comment: I think that whe `deleteDimension` is used, the rows are deleted instead of the clear the rows. So I'm worry that your script is different from your actuatl script. How about this? For example, when you want to delete the row 256, when you use `255` and `256` to `startIndex` and `endIndex`, respectively, what result will you obtain?

Comment: Hi Tanaike! Thank you, that works. I tried that before and it didn't work, I must have had something else going on in the program, but changing the indices works!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When you r issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to solve the problem and get the result I wanted (Thank you Tanaike!)

Since I wanted to delete at `dataidx` I had my startIndex set as `dataidx-1`

````py
spreadsheet_data = [{"deleteDimension": {"range": {"sheetId": 0,"dimension": "ROWS","startIndex": dataidx-1,"endIndex": dataidx}}}]
    update_data= {"requests": spreadsheet_data}
    request = SERVICESHEET.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SHEETID, body=update_data)
    response = request.execute()```
````